# Prove $\operatorname{func}(f)=\sum_{i=1}^{m}\frac{n_i}{f^2}\left(1-\frac{1}{f}\right)^{n-n_i}$ has a maximal value.

Tags: calculus

I have two questions about the function:

$\operatorname{func}(f)=\sum_{i=1}^{m}\frac{n_i}{f^2}\left(1-\frac{1}{f}\right)^{n-n_i}$

where elements are subject to the conditions:

1. $\sum_{i=1}^m n_i=n$;
2. $n_i$ and $n$ $\in \mathbb{N}$;
3. $m$ and $f$  $\in \mathbb{Z}^+$.

I). Prove a unique maximum exists with respect to $f$ exists for fixed $n_i$, $m$.

II). Also, i would like to know if the function has a upper bound solution for $f$ when $\operatorname{func}(f)$ has a maxima.

My thought:

Find the derivative of $\operatorname{func}(f)$ of $f$, then let the result equals $0$. But it seems difficult to calculate. It is my first time use stackexchange, any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Please share your thoughts so far :)

Comment: Thanks, I'd like to share my thoughts. I have already reedited my question as you said.

Comment: To clarify: do you want to prove a maximum exists with respect to $f$ exists for fixed $n_i,m $, or do you want to prove that a maximum exists with respect to $f,n_i,m$?

Comment: I wanna prove a maximum exists with respect to $f$ exists for fixed $n_i$, $m$. Also, i would like to know if the function has a approximate analysis solution for $f$ when $\operatorname{func}(f)$ has a maxima.

Answer (score 1):

To show that $\text{func}(f)$ has  a maxima, it is enough to show this series converges.

We can write this as $$\left(1-\dfrac{1}{f}\right)^{n+1}\sum_{i = 1}^{m} \dfrac{n_i}{f^2}\left(1-\dfrac{1}{f}\right)^{-n_i-1} $$

$ $

$$=-\left(1-\dfrac{1}{f}\right)^{n+1}\sum_{i = 1}^{m} \left(1-\dfrac{1}{f}\right)^{-n_i} $$

$ $

Comment: May you show me more prompts? I cannot understand your idea clearly.